# Checkbox in front of multi-line paragraph CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the check boxes to appear before the start of the paragraph but they are appearing on the bottom line of the paragraph if the text is too long. Note that I want the text to go to a new line if it exceeds the witdth of the div.

HTML example:

```
<label>
    <div class='note_div'>
        <input type='checkbox'>
        <p class='note'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tincidunt nunc condimentum suscipit hendrerit. Duis blandit purus lacus, at adipiscing sapien volutpat in. Curabitur tristique nisi quis sem malesuada ultricies. Curabitur venenatis gravida ligula, vel molestie odio blandit ut. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec fermentum vel nulla id porttitor. Pellentesque quis molestie leo. Nunc quis ligula ultricies, hendrerit enim nec, elementum ante. Praesent quam erat, facilisis id dolor a, gravida varius ligula. Praesent placerat, ipsum in euismod consectetur, eros libero</p>
    </div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.note_div {
    width: 350px;
}

.note {
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3RfL8/

Thanks!

Comment: Add `[type=checkbox] {vertical-align:top;}` to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```
.note {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ENY6v/1/)

Alternatively, you could also use [floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) instead of inline blocks:

```
.note_div > input {
    float: left;
}
.note {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ENY6v/2/)